# Перенаправление ввода капчи для программы Java

Tags: java, recaptcha, captcha

**Проблема в следующем:**

Есть Java сервер, который парсит различные сайты и как и полагается, его ловит Капча и просит ввести ее.

**Задача:** Как только мы понимаем, что нас просят ввести капчу - программа останавливается и кидает нам ссылку с "проверкой", мы вводим (предположим в той же программе, из разряда основной поток останавливается, программа запрашивает у нас слова для ввода капчи или ссылку с введенной каптчей (тут есть некоторые проблемы)) и дальше продолжает работать до следующего инцидента.

**Трудности:**

1. Когда я останавливаю программу на моменте ввода капчи, сам ее ввожу, копирую ссылку с введеннйо каптчей и вставляю программу - каптча не проходит. Потому что по этой ссылке открывается новая каптча. Т.е. состояние не запоминается и каждый раз генерируется новая.
2. Если просто в браузере заходить на сайт, то каптча не требуется. Программно User_Agent, referer и прочие хедеры проставляю.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли какая то возможность решения данной задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Когда я останавливаю программу на моменте ввода капчи, сам ее ввожу, копирую ссылку с введеннйо каптчей и вставляю программу - каптча не проходит. Потому что по этой ссылке открывается новая каптча.

Что логично. Вы должны сами скачивать капчу, отдавать скачанные картинки (а не ссылку) в обработку, а потом продолжать выполнение вводом кода

> Если просто в браузере заходить на сайт, то каптча не требуется. Программно User_Agent, referer и прочие хедеры проставляю.

Вариантов куча:

1. Робот работает значительно быстрее пользователя
2. На странице висит какой-нибудь JavaScript, который выполняется в браузере, но который не выполняет робот
3. ...

Comment: Я понял, о чем Вы говорите. Но проблема сохранилась. 
Я перехватываю url с капчей, выкачиваю документ и в этом документе есть непосредственно ссылка на картинку с ней. 
Вручную распознаю текст, ввожу правильный ответ и создаю новое соединение на этом же сервере с ссылкой ввода правильного ответа капчи. 
Но, к сожалению, никакие трюки с установлением всех хедэров в соединении, не помогают.

Comment: Возможно есть какой-то способ без установления нового соединения, а в  текущее URLConnection засунуть новую ссылку с введенной капчей?

Comment: @МишаковАлександр А куки вы обрабатываете? Вам не URLConnection нужен, а HttpClient

Comment: Спасибо большое! HttpClient действительно справился с поставленной задачей.